# JavaScript push returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-push

I know that this thing was already questioned, but really, I have not found anything useful or understandable.

I have this code:

```
var pdfListPath = [];

function listDir(path) {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
    function(fileSystem) {
      var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
      reader.readEntries(
        function(entries) {
          console.log(entries);
          for (var i = 0; i == entries.length; i++) {
            pdfListPath.push(entries[i]);
          };
        },
        function(err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      );
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
};

var pdfList = listDir(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/pdf/");
console.log(pdfList);
console.log(pdfListPath);
```

What I expected was the `pdfListPath` filled with something, but what I get in the console is an "undefined."

The `entries` instead is a filled array, so what is wrong with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you code is **asynchronous**, you need to move `console.log(pdfListPath);` just after the **for loop** inside the handler function

Comment: TL;DR, `console.log(pdfList)` happens before the inner functions get called asynchronously. The real values are only available inside those inner functions (or use Promises and/or `async` functions)

Comment: `function listDir(path, successHandler, errorHandler){ window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, fileSystem => fileSystem.createReader().readEntries(successHandler, errorHandler), errorHandler) }` or better, you check out Promises; avoids callback hell in your code.

Answer (score 3):

your for loop is wrong you need to change

```
for (var i = 0; i == entries.length; i++) {
    pdfListPath.push(entries[i]);
};
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    pdfListPath.push(entries[i]);
};
```

(not 100% sure, maybe it's even `<=` you better check `i` and `entries.length`)

Comment: thank you, but the problem is not this one